# Typescript namespace not resolved during runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am very new to Java script module constructs as well as to Typescript.

I am trying to import an namespace and all the exported members under that.

Typescript i am trying to refer/import from my file is
https://github.com/agea/CmisJS/blob/master/src/cmis.ts

In this ts file a namespace called "cmis" is exported like this

```
export namespace cmis {
```

I am trying to refer/import this in another file same as in
https://github.com/agea/CmisJS/blob/master/src/cmis.spec.ts

like this `import { cmis } from 'cmis';`

I did all the dependency resolution in npm and design time dependency in Visual Studio code is working fine.

My package.json

```
   {
  "title": "sdm-nodejsclient",
  "name": "cmsdm-nodejsclientis",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "a CMIS client library written in Typescript for node and the browser",
  "author": {
    "name": "Saurav Sarkar",
    "email": "saurav.sarkar1@gmail.com"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^25.1.3",
    "@types/node": "^13.7.4",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "cmis": "~1.0.2",
    "cross-fetch": "~1.1.1",
    "es6-promise": "~4.2.4",
    "isomorphic-base64": "~1.0.2",
    "isomorphic-form-data": "~1.0.0",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "mocha": "^7.0.1",
    "ts-jest": "^25.2.1",
    "url-search-params-polyfill": "~2.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "~4.1.2",
    "@types/mocha": "~2.2.48",
    "@types/node": "~8.5.2",
    "chai": "~4.1.2",
    "cmis": "~1.0.2",
    "mocha": "~5.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "~2.0.3",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.6",
    "typedoc": "~0.10.0",
    "typescript": "~2.7.1",
    "uglify-js": "~3.3.7",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "~1.1.8",
    "webpack": "~3.10.0"
  }
}
```

But whenever i try to run the same code, it is failing with TypeError: Cannot read property 'CmisSession' of undefined at

```
let session = new cmis.CmisSession(url);
```

index.d.ts in the  source library

```
export * from './src/cmis';
```

So ,node runtime is not able to resolve the cmis namespace imported and vClearly seems to be runtime dependency issue.

Best Regards,
Saurav

Answer (score 0):

The namespace is not a value in TypeScript so it shouldn't contain any implementation, only type definition.

For example:

```js
// types.d.ts
// This is ok
declare namespace MySpace {
  type Calc = (a: number, b: number) => number;
}
```

Calc is not a function, just type. We can use types to say compiler what are things (for example functions). But we can't execute types. **Types is something like meta data and it removes from code during compilation**. This is wy `CmisSession` is undefined.

```js
// types.d.ts
// This is wrong! Type definition contains implementation.
declare namespace MySpace {
  type Calc = (a: number, b: number) => { return a + b; };
}
```

Implementation should not mixed with type definition.
Implementation function calc:

```js
// index.ts
const calc: MySpace.Calc = (a, b) => a + b;
```

Don't need to declare types inside implementation. This is why namespaces comes and helps describe the code.

Comment: @e.vyushin...thanks for looking this up...but if you see the code of cmis.ts i don;t see any implementation being done inside namespace..infact the namespace "cmis" is not declared but exported only...may be i am missing something simple

Comment: The cmis package.json doesn't contain some necessary properties such as `main` and `types`. This can lead to import errors. Try import cmis from dist directly.
```typescript
import { cmis } from './node_modules/cmis/dist/cmis';
const session = new cmis.CmisSession('url');
```